# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<projectName.app>/<projectName>:didSelectItemAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, app-store, ios9, xcode7.3

I'm getting this warning while submitting the app to the Apps store through organizer:

> The app references non-public selectors in
> Payload/.app/:didSelectItemAtIndex

How can I solve this problem?

As far as I know, this warning comes when the application had used the third party API, so please find the below list.

1. GHWalkThrough
2. SDWebImage
3. Reachability
4. SWRevealViewController
5. NSData+Base64